# Issues after export of a symfony2 project to another computer

Tags: symfony, export

i would like to export a current project to another computer. I installed symfony, composer and everything on the new computer export the database. Then i simply copy pasted the current project's folder (from my www) to the new computer. When i launch the url, i've got the index page of my project, but some routes dont't work. I tried to do a cache:clear or a composer:update but nothing work. Is there a "clean" way to export a project ? Thanks
ah and i have error in my "vendor folder" in eclipse (friendofsymfony and symfony) i don't know why

Comment: If you answer your own question, type it up as an answer for future readers.

Comment: i don't understand, i didnt replied to my own questio... the "vendor" error was about an xml conflict in eclipse, i corrected it but i stll get "no route exist" in my project. I did a route:debug, all the routes exist, but i can't reach them...

Comment: i finaly resolved my issues by reinstalling all my components. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be copying the files that way. Consider using a git repository.